# Visualising non-euclidean geometry

Tags: geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

Apologies in advance if this question is too simple! I'm learning about non-Euclidean geometry & am wondering about how the practical visualizations work.

Quite often textbooks show diagrams where there's a triangle drawn on a sphere as an example of spherical geometry. My question is, if I got an actual ball and drew on it would that be an example of non-euclidean geometry? And similarly, is the attachted picture (of the
Shah Nematollah Vali Shrine) an example of non-euclidean geometry and if not why not?

[image]

Comment: I cannot see any attached picture. Maybe you want to re-try to include it. Or maybe include a ink to the desired picture so folks here could see it.

Comment: @coffeemath Sorry, I've just edited it to include it now!

Comment: It is indeed pretty, Doesn't look spherical, slightly bulged. But geometry is done on such 2 dimensional surfaces like the dome in your photo. There is a notion of "geodesic" which roughly  means shortest path (with path staying on surface) between two points on the surface. [To get a more accurate definition try googling "geodesic".]